# Can I raytrace gravitational lensing using only a single point source of gravity?

Tags: raytracing

I'd like to simulate the magnification of very distant objects by the lensing effect of a less distant galaxy. Will I need to model large numbers of point masses or can I get away with just a single average point mass?

I can see how to raytrace using hyperbolae for the rays influenced by a single point mass, but I wouldn't know where to begin with multiple point masses. So before I attempt to build this raytracer I'd like to know whether I'm going to be able to avoid multiple masses, and still have believable results.

Comment: This might be a better question for [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) or [Astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/). I know a point mass does produce lensing effects (see e.g. [this](http://spiro.fisica.unipd.it/~antonell/schwarzschild/)) but no idea if a galaxy can be well-approximated by a point mass for something like this.

Answer (score 10):

As you have probably observed, in general, you cannot solve in closed-form the equations for ray trajectories around multiple distorting objects.

The standard approach for such things is just to discretize it.  This looks like Eulerian integration.  Just step your ray a little bit toward the object, calculate gravity from all sources and bend it, then step it more, und so weiter.  This is called *raymarching*.

Since you're interested in problems on an astrophysical scale, you can assume the ray is linear far enough away from the object, with minimal error.

---

Here's a scene I rendered a while ago using a homebrew photonmapper (no QMC) using this raymarching technique.

I present: relativistic photon mapping: black hole in a Cornell box!
[image: black hole in a Cornell box]